# Dimension estimate of certain globally generated line bundles on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a projective algebraic curve in $\mathbb P^n$(over $\mathbb C$) of genus $g$. Let's assume we have the family of base point free line bundles of degree $d$ on $C$ having exactly $2$ independent global sections is non-empty.

Then is there a way to know the least dimension of the the following sub family of the above mentioned base point free line bundles :$\{L \in Pic^d(C) |h^0(L)=2 , h^0(\mathcal O_C(m) \otimes L^*) =0\}$ ? I mean in terms of its genus and degree?[Here $m \in \mathbb N$]

can we say under some assumption on its degree the sub-collection is non-empty?

For that kind of line bundles from Riemann-Roch theorem we have, $h^0(\mathcal O_C(-m) \otimes L \otimes K_C) =1-g-deg(\mathcal O_C(m) \otimes L^*) =1-g - deg(\mathcal O_C(m)) + deg(L)$ .Now for $deg(L) =g$ we should have $ h^0(\mathcal O_C(-m) \otimes L \otimes K_C) = 1- deg(\mathcal O_C(m))$. I don't see why that should happen.

Can someone give me a reference?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: What does $O_C(C)$ mean for you?

Comment: @Mohan, Now I have edited the question with $\mathcal O_C(C)$ replaced by $\mathcal O_C(m)$.